# Mongo Aggregation: Use $count of found documents for query

Tags: mongodb, dictionary, count, let

I have a Mongo collection *series* where each document has a list with *dataPoints*.
All *series* with the same *testStepId* contain the same amount of *dataPoints*:

```
{
  "seriesId": {
    "seriesId": "77678ca1-31db-4cec-a042-68a3053b92c6"
  },
  "testStepId": {
    "testStepId": "c152415b-2392-4c2b-af74-51a4973bd257"
  },
  "measurement": {
    "startTime": {
      "$date": "2020-07-07T12:40:49.782Z"
    },
    "endTime": {
      "$date": "2020-07-07T12:42:19.782Z"
    }
  },
  "dataPoints": [
    {
      "timeStamp": {
        "$date": "2020-07-07T12:41:09.782Z"
      },
      "value": "Value_1_1"
    },
    {
      "timeStamp": {
        "$date": "2020-07-07T12:41:29.782Z"
      },
      "value": "Value_1_2"
    },
    {
      "timeStamp": {
        "$date": "2020-07-07T12:41:39.782Z"
      },
      "value": "Value_1_3"
    },
    ...
    {
      "timeStamp": {
        "$date": "2020-07-07T12:42:19.782Z"
      },
      "value": "Value_2_11"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I want to query all *series* documents that match a specific *testStepId* (no problem).
But instead of loading all *dataPoints* of all found *series* I want to load in sum only 1000 *dataPoints*.
So in case of 10 found *series* I have to load only 100 *dataPoints* per *series*:

-> Load every *(dataPoints.size() / 100)-th dataPoint*

-> This means I have to consider the count of found *series* documents and the count of *dataPoints* in the series

-> Load every X-th *dataPoint* where

```
X = 1000 / <count of documents> / <count of dataPoints>
```

I'm trying hard to get this done via aggregation with the [MongoDB Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass). But I'm still failing with counting the found documents and unsing this value ...

To start simple I just try to get every 2nd *dataPoint*:

```
{
    project: {
        dataPoints: {
            $map: {
                input: { $range: [ 0, {"$size": "$dataPoints"}, 2 ] },
                as: "index",
                in: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$dataPoints", "$$index" ] }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

-> Works fine

Now I want to get every x-th 'dataPoint' dependend on the count of found documents.
For this I tried some different ways, none of them works ...

1. try: Use *$count* instead of fixed number:

```
{
    project: {
        dataPoints: {
            $map: {
                input: { $range: [ 0, {"$size": "$dataPoints"}, $count ] },
                as: "index",
                in: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$dataPoints", "$$index" ] }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

-> *"Project specification must be an object"*

2. try: Define the *count* as variable:

```
{
    project: {
        dataPoints: {
            $let: {
                vars: { 
                    total: "$count",
                },
                in: { 
                    $map: {
                        input: { $range: [ 0, {"$size": "$dataPoints"}, "$$total"] },
                        as: "index",
                        in: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$dataPoints", "$$index" ] }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

-> *"$range requires a numeric value step, found value of type:missing"*

Obviously my approach is wrong.
Could any body give me some hint how to get this working?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `X = <count of dataPoints> *  <count of documents> / 1000` ?

Comment: You're right, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the formula for `X` is `X = <count of dataPoints> * <count of documents> / 1000`

You can not directly access the number of documents (count) at a particular aggregation pipeline stage. However, you can combine all documents into a single document and count them, then expand them back into separate documents. You can achieve this by using `$group` or `$facet`.

I'll show an example with `$group`

```
[
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      count: { $sum: 1 },
      all: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$all"
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: { // $replaceWith is available from v4.2, for earlier version use { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: <doc> } }
      $mergeObjects: [
        "$all",
        {
          dataPoints: {
            $map: {
              input: {
                $range: [
                  0,
                  { $size: "$all.dataPoints" },
                  {
                    $ceil: {
                      $divide: [
                        {
                          $multiply: [
                            { "$size": "$all.dataPoints" },
                            "$count"
                          ]
                        },
                        1000
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
              as: "index",
              in: { $arrayElemAt: ["$all.dataPoints", "$$index"] }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wurI_oJsaE4)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm going to go in this direction. Didn't know Mongo Playground so far ...

Comment: Don't forget to update the question with the correct formula. Feel free to upvote or accept the answer if you think the answer is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Found a really good solution with support from an mongo expert:

```
[{
    //
    // Group the series
    //
    '$group': {
        '_id': {
            'seriesName': '$series.seriesName'
        }, 
        'dataPoints': {
            '$push': '$dataPoints'
        }, 
        'series': {
            '$addToSet': '$series'
        }
    }
}, 
{
    //
    // Concat the dataPoints for each series into on array
    //
    '$addFields': {
        'dataPoints': {
            '$reduce': {
                'input': '$dataPoints', 
                'initialValue': [], 
                'in': {
                    '$concatArrays': [
                        '$$value', '$$this'
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, 
{
    //
    // Calculate 'x' for 'find every x-th dataPoint' (called index here)
    // 
    '$replaceWith': {
        'dataPoints': {
            '$map': {
                'input': {
                    '$range': [
                        0, {
                            '$size': '$dataPoints'
                        }, {
                            '$ceil': {
                                '$divide': [
                                    {
                                        '$size': '$dataPoints'
                                    }, 100
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                'as': 'index', 
                'in': {
                    '$arrayElemAt': [
                        '$dataPoints', '$$index'
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}]
```

Hint: this will not return the exact number of dataPoints, rather a proximity. But thats exactly what I need ...

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3YTNedYvbah)